# jquery create selector in drag to be used in drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am new to jQuery and I'm trying to use the draggable and droppable interactions. Is there a way to set the droppable selector when the box is dragged? I've tried parsing the draggable selector in the drag event, setting a value to a variable and using the variable as the droppable selector but the variable never gets changed when the drop event is executed. Here is my JSFiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/tjohnson/DNxpv/161/

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "set the droppable selector"?

Comment: the $(this) in `drag: SetSelector($(this).attr("id")),` isn't your object.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$(section).droppable({...})` that only applies to whatever value `section` had *at the time you called it*.

You can't go and change `section` later (per your `SetSection` function) and expect your previous call to `.droppable` to still apply.

You need to call `.droppable()` *inside* your `SetSection` function - it necessary removing the droppable state from whichever element previously had it.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/DNxpv/165/

Did you mean something like this?

I did the binding and unbinding of the droppable selector in the start and stop events! Furthermore I tweaked the Selector method a bit.